# Trying to open Outlook DefaultProfileName only

Tags: outlook

Could someone please suggest how I can $Outlook.Application.DefaultProfileName without breaking the variables.

Add-Member : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
At C:\FindOutlookPSTsMike.ps1:14 char:21
+ $Object | Add-Member <<<<  -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'ComputerName' -Value $ComputerName
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-Member], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddMemberCo
   mmand

Add-Member : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
At C:\FindOutlookPSTsMike.ps1:15 char:21
+ $Object | Add-Member <<<<  -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'UserName' -Value $UserName
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-Member], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddMemberCo
   mmand

Export-Csv : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
At C:\FindOutlookPSTsMike.ps1:16 char:21
+ $Object | Export-Csv <<<<  -NoTypeInformation \UK-PR-EXMC02\PSTLOG\$UserName-$ComputerName-OpenPSTs-$Date.csv
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Export-Csv], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCo
   mmand

---

```
$Date = Get-Date -format d-M-yyyy
$UserName = $env:USERNAME
$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME

$Outlook = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application
$Profile = $Outlook.Application.DefaultProfileName 

$Object = $Profile.Session.Stores | Where {$_.FilePath -like "*.PST"} | Select `
     @{Expression={$_.DisplayName}; Label="PST Name in Outlook"},`
     @{Expression={$_.FilePath}; Label="PST Location/FileName"},`
     @{Expression={$_.IsOpen}; Label="PST Open in Outlook"},`
     @{Expression={(Get-Item $_.FilePath).Length / 1KB}; Label="PST File Size (KB)"}
$Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'ComputerName' -Value $ComputerName
$Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'UserName' -Value $UserName
$Object | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation \\<NetworkShareName>\$UserName-$ComputerName-OpenPSTs-$Date.csv

Start-Sleep 5
Get-Process | Where {$_.Name -like "Outlook*"} | Stop-Process
```

Answer (score 0):

Application.DefaultProfileName returns a string with the name of the profile, not an object. Are you trying to enumerate PST files in a particular profile?

Comment: Thank you for responding. Yes trying to grab a list of configured psts in the default profile.

Comment: Replace the line $Object = $Profile.Session.Stores with $Object = $Outlook.Session.Stores. You might also want to look at http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/profman_examples.htm#example2

Comment: The script runs fine like this.                              $Outlook = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application
$Object = $Outlook.Session.Stores | Where {$_.FilePath -like "*.PST"} | Select ..... The problem I have is when Outlook has two profiles, I need to auto logon to the default profile.

Comment: If Outlook is already running, you will always connect to the profile that Outlook is already using (Outlook is a singleton). Nothing you can do short of using Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) or Redemption (it exposes RDOStore.Stores collection, and its RDOPstStore object exposes PstPath property.